# Calling Data from Controller to HTML view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code in Plunkr.  http://plnkr.co/edit/8sBafktFzFa8fCLLJgMF

this is my js file

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {



  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',
      size: size
    });

    var applicantID = 12;
  };


  $scope.submit_info = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent1.html',
      controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',
      size: size
    });
  };
});
```

this is my html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>

            <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="submit_info('lg')">Submit</button>

    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent1.html">

            <h3>CaseID: </h3>
            {{ applicantID }}

    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Set caseID</button>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to assign applicantID upon clicking the button "setID" and upon clicking button "submit",it displays the applicantID value that was passed which is '12'. But it keeps passing an empty data.

Comment: Where is the reference to Angular, where is ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

You need the ng-app, and to remove this $modal, I fixed your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u0nhwa4w/2/

```
angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp',[])
.controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, $http, $sce) {
   var applicantID;
    $scope.submit_info = function() {
            applicantID = 12;
            getusercaseID(applicantID); 
    };

   var getusercaseID = function(id) {
    $scope.page_data = id;
    console.log("yes come on ");
    console.log($scope.page_data);
   };
});
```

Comment: $modal is not part of Angular core, so you need to add a library for it if you want to use it.

Comment: Oh, you also need the [] in angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp',[])

Comment: i added the code only from my controller hence why i didnt attach the ngApp part my bad. Also $modal is there bcos in my code i call a $modal and the applicantID is the data i want to pass to the modal. The only difference with what you implemented was the button triggering the response. In my code i hv a submit button tht triggers it but it doesnt work hence why i made it ng-init in d fiddle file. My code is very long as it has http posts nd all. I dont see much difference with your code and mine. Maybe i will update it with the modal part for more clarification. thanks RTPMatt

Comment: for my code. another function triggers submit.info() so the button cannot trigger it. Is there anyway d value in getusercaseID can be triggered thru d submit.info() and displayed on the view?

Comment: here is an updated plunkr file with a perefect replication of my code. http://plnkr.co/edit/8sBafktFzFa8fCLLJgMF